# Raylib Texture position on the window not aligning with the actual texture loaded in

Tags: c++, raylib

[image: As you can see the mouse pointer coordinates are the same with the texture coordinates, but the texture is displayed elsewhere]

Here's my code:

```
#include "raylib.h"
#include "raymath.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "rlgl.h"

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 600
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 600
#define SPACESHIP_WIDTH 221
#define SPACESHIP_HEIGHT 289

Texture2D spaceship;


int main() {
    SetConfigFlags(FLAG_WINDOW_RESIZABLE | FLAG_VSYNC_HINT);
    InitWindow(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, "New Game");
    SetWindowMinSize(320, 240);
    SetTargetFPS(60);

    spaceship = LoadTexture("/home/thanos/Downloads/ship.png");
    Rectangle source = (Rectangle){0,0, SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT};
    Rectangle destination = (Rectangle){SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2, source.width/2, source.height/2};
    Vector2 spaceshipPosition = (Vector2){destination.width/2, destination.height/2};
    
    float spaceshipRotation = 15.0f;

    while(!WindowShouldClose()){
        Vector2 mouse = GetMousePosition();

        BeginDrawing();

            ClearBackground(LIGHTGRAY);

            DrawTexturePro(spaceship, source, destination, spaceshipPosition, spaceshipRotation * GetTime(), WHITE);
            
            DrawLineV((Vector2){300, 300}, spaceshipPosition, BLACK);  

            DrawText(TextFormat("Default Mouse: [%i , %i]", (int)mouse.x, (int)mouse.y), 400, 25, 20, RED);
            DrawText(TextFormat("[Ship position] X: [%i] Y: [%i]", (int)spaceshipPosition.x, (int)spaceshipPosition.y), 400, 40, 20, RED);

        EndMode2D();
        EndDrawing();
    }
    CloseWindow();
    return 0;
}
```

I have also drawn a line from the center of the window to the spaceship location, and as you can see it's also not working as expected.
There are 2 possibilities:

- Either the code to show the coordinates of the mouse and the texture is wrong.
- Or something is wrong with the actual png of the texture. I can upload the spaceship.png too if needed, but it's 221x289 pixels.

Comment: spaceshipPosition = {destination.width, destination.height}/2 = {source.width/2, source.height/2}/2 = {SPACESHIP_WIDTH/4, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT/4} which works out to {55, 72}.

Answer (score 1):

`spaceshipPosition` is not named correctly. It is in fact the origin of the sprite *local to the sprite*. Your actual center of the spaceship is at {destination.x - source.x, destination.y - source.y}, which should indeed be {300, 300}.

This is plain to see in the implementation of this function:

```
            float x = dest.x - origin.x;
            float y = dest.y - origin.y;
            topLeft = (Vector2){ x, y };
            topRight = (Vector2){ x + dest.width, y };
            bottomLeft = (Vector2){ x, y + dest.height };
            bottomRight = (Vector2){ x + dest.width, y + dest.height };
```